# Convertir URL (string) de la base de datos a link en HTML

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, .net, mvc, script

Antes que nada, perdon si la pregunta ya fue hecha o si no me doy a entender bien. Soy un poco nuevo y busco implementar esto.
Estoy utilizando .NET MVC y MYSQL

La idea es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, una de las entradas es "Visitar posteo".
Mi objetivo es que esa entrada despliegue (con un efecto accordion) un string que viene almacenado de la base de datos (por ejemplo "www.facebook.com/post") y convertirlo en link para que el usuario tan solo le haga click y lo redireccione a esa pagina.

Desde ya, muchisimas gracias. Espero haber sido claro con la consulta.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla es cambiar el control donde tienes "Visitar posteo" por un "LinkLabel" y en el código especificar en el evento "LinckClicked" la URL a la quieres redirigir al usuario. Por ejemplo

```
    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.facebook.com/post");
}
```

Dónde `linkLabel1` es el nombre que le habrás puesto al control `linkLabel`.